# Sqoop import TCP/IP Connection Refused

Tags: sql-server, sqoop

Sqoop list-tables , sqoop eval is successful 
But fails in Sqoop import.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433; database=Runtime" --username ** --password ****** --table live -m 1
```

The error is :

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.xxx.xxx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop eval and Sqoop list tables requires only the Name node connection with the SQL server.

But for SQOOP import, all the nodes in the cluster needs to have access to the remote SQL server.

Here the Telnet failed from datanodes.

It was due the network settings and firewalls configuration.

Later when every node was able to access the Remote SQL server the SQOOP IMPORT was successful.